# c# HttpClient connection keepalive

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, httpclient, keep-alive, ashx

i have a Demo ashx webservice like this:

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        //string s = context.Request.Form["prova"];
        string a= context.Request.Form["a"];
        string b= context.Request.Form["b"];

        TryKeepAlive();
        context.Response.Write("ok");
    }
```

where trykeepalive just does:

```
    private void TryKeepAlive()
    {
        int msTimeout = 999999999;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(msTimeout);
    }
```

this is just a demo, but i have the same problem of keeping connection alive in another real method.

from phone i'm calling the post via HttpClient:

```
    public async void PostIt()
    {
        string url = "myurl.htm";
        var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("a", "12345"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("b", "123456")
                };
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

the code works, my only problem is keeping connection alive for all time.
can someone tell me how to do it? i read about the method keepAlive(), can someone show me how to implement it? thanks

Answer (score 1):

`request.KeepAlive = true;` If I'm not mistaken, I wanted to comment but I lack rep, sorry for posting it as an answer, if someone can comment this suggestion I'll gladly delete my answer.

Comment: Np, i had the same problem yesterday, no rep for comments.
I read for the .keepalive = true, my problem is how to use it in HttpClient call, couse i can't do httpClient.KeepAlive couse it doesn't exist

Comment: I think (not sure) that with httpclient its by default set to true, I was confusing myself with the `.keepalive` suggestion

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot, but the problem, as i found now, is that windows phone has default timeout set to 60 seconds, and setting keepalive doesn't change it, if someone know how to change this value will solve lot of my problems. thanks anyway